# Manually triggering a low active pin

Tags: microcontroller, reset, trigger

I have a microcontroller with an active low reset pin. This pin is connected to a timer that periodically triggers a low edge and resets the microcontroller. 
What would be the best circuit that would allow me to also manually trigger the reset pin through an external circuit while the pin is connected to the timer? Shorting the two together would obviously not work.

Comment: What kind of timer? Post the link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When either the timer output or the GPIO goes low, \$ \overline{\text{INT}}\$ goes low, so the gate is a positive true AND, 1/4 of an HC08 or somesuch.

[image]

or, better yet,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your timer output is a push-pull circuit?

If you can configure it to be open-drain, then you just need a pull-up resistor on the reset line, and use a switch to short the reset input to ground.

If you can't configure the Timer output to be open-drain, then  you just need a series resistor between the timer output (say 1k) and the reset input. Again, the reset switch shorts the reset input to ground.

Answer (score -1):

`SW1` can be pressed in order to generate the reset independent of timer. Whenever the `SW1` is pressed first transistor turns on and `RST#` net will be pulled low to ground. Whenever the Timer is driving low, the first transistor will turn on and  `RST#` line will go low and a low level voltage will be presented to the MCU `RESET#` Pin.

When either switch or TimerOutput is low, Q3 will have a base current of about 8 mA (assuming VCC as 5 V, Vbe as 0.8 and diode drop of 0.4 V), which will sufficiently to saturate Q3. Q4 too will be saturated so that, the Vol will be less than 0.1 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3a3Ws.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What if the switch is pulled up? I expect the final design to be a gpio instead of a switch. The gpio will be pulled down to trigger the reset.

Comment: @Malfunction Sorry for the silly mistake.

Comment: Doesn't work: lowest possible level of ouput will be ca. 1.4V, which is to high for L.

Comment: @Curd pls check now. Sorry for ignoring

Comment: Now logic output level is OK, but still another problem: base resistor R9 is only 100 Ohm, i.e. ca. 36mA at Vcc=5V; might be too much load for TimerOutput. BTW R8 and R9 can be shared.

Comment: @Curd assuming 5 V now, the TimerOutput need to sink about 7.9 mA. Nice correction of sharing the resistors, Else the current will be more when both go low simultaneously.

Comment: You can make the base resistor realy big (several 10kOhm). Q3 will amplifiy the current at least by factor 100 (or saturate). The same is true for R7/Q4

Comment: @Curd the hFE is only about 10 to 20 for selected transistor at saturation. So, i thought of low value for base resistors. Hope it still works